# Why pass constants into Bundle objects putString() method?

Tags: java, android

I am looking at a tutorial and don't understand why he decided to pass in constants. The same constants are made in the next activity that that the data is being passed into, why so? The only use for constants I have been aware of thus far is for stuff like pi and other math constants.

ListActivity.java

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DerpAdapter.ItemClickCallback {
private static final String BUNDLE_EXTRAS = "BUNDLE_EXTRAS";
private static final String EXTRA_QUOTE = "EXTRA_QUOTE";
private static final String EXTRA_ATTR = "EXTRA_ATTR";

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DerpAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList listData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    listData = (ArrayList) DerpData.getListData();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rec_list);
    //LayoutManager controls if you are using Linear, staggard etc. It controls the views.
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    adapter = new DerpAdapter(DerpData.getListData(), this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setItemClickCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int p) {
    ListItem item = (ListItem) listData.get(p);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString(EXTRA_QUOTE, item.getTitle());
    extras.putString(EXTRA_ATTR, item.getSubTitle());
    i.putExtra(BUNDLE_EXTRAS, extras);

    startActivity(i);
}


@Override
public void onSecondaryIconClick(int p) {
    ListItem item = (ListItem) listData.get(p);
    //update our data
    if (item.isFavourite()){
        item.setFavourite(false);
    } else {
        item.setFavourite(true);
    }
    //pass new data to adapter and update
    adapter.setListData(listData);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

DetailActivity.java

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String BUNDLE_EXTRAS = "BUNDLE_EXTRAS";
private static final String EXTRA_QUOTE = "EXTRA_QUOTE";
private static final String EXTRA_ATTR = "EXTRA_ATTR";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getBundleExtra(BUNDLE_EXTRAS);

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_quote_text)).setText(extras.getString(EXTRA_QUOTE));
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_quote_attribution)).setText(extras.getString(EXTRA_ATTR));
}
```

Comment: Because if you do not use constants, it could get messy at some point. I am not saying about this example, but these variables should be public and should have written in once into DetailActivity or ListActivity based on your design.

Comment: easy to use, easy to remember, easy to modify and clean code